# Change bootorder on Dell computers with UEFI

Tags: boot, bios, dell-latitude, pxe

Does anyone know a way to change the bootorder from inside the OS (Windows 7/10) on Dell computers?
It is working fine with legacy mode and using [cctk](https://www.dell.com/support/article/sg/en/sgdhs1/sln311126/dell-client-configuration-toolkit-cctk?lang=en) but does not seem to have any effect when the clients have UEFI.
I need this because a solution to PXE boot clients (reinstall the OS) without initiating a OS installation from inside the current OS (like for with SCCM).

This works fine on legacy

```
cctk bootorder --sequence=embnic1,hdd
```

But not in UEFI.

Comment: Do you need it to be a no touch solution? For instance, you want to change the boot order remotely then reboot the computer and have it automatically boot in to PXE?

Comment: Exactly like that. Zero touch

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use cctk.exe ForcePxeOnNextBoot=Enabled

Comment: ForcePxeOnNextBoot is not very reliable in my opinion, changing the boot order works on many more models.

Comment: You are right, but I was not able to figure it out, how to change the bootorder via cctk when the clients running with UEFI. If you can share a functional solution, this would be great, for me, also for many other people facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell script - found somwhere, I am not Author but Modifier.
The script changes boot order IPv4 embeded NIC card 1st and disable IPv6 boot.
Requires to set BIOS password to empty ( for me by SCCM TaskSequence step ) or provide password in script or manually by parameter:

```
param (
[string]$biospwd = $( Read-Host "Input BIOS password please and press Enter ..." )
 )
# Clear BIOS password
.\cctk.cmd --setuppwd= --valsetuppwd=$biospwd
.
.
# Fill BIOS password back
.\cctk.cmd --setuppwd=$biospwd
```

---

CCTK 3.x for older models like OP3010, 3020 with HAPI drivers required, CCTK 4.x without HAPI for newer models. Results could be checked in Windows\Logs\uefi*.txt files.

---

```
$SerialNumber = $(Get-WmiObject win32_bios).SerialNumber
$UEFIfileName = "$Env:SystemRoot\Logs\uefiBootOrder_" + $SerialNumber + "_Source" + ".txt"
$UEFIfileNameAfter = "$Env:SystemRoot\Logs\uefiBootOrder_" + $SerialNumber + "_AfterChange" + ".txt"

.\cctk.cmd bootorder --bootlisttype=uefi --valsetuppwd= > $UEFIfileName

foreach($line in Get-Content $UEFIfileName) {
# For OP3010 and OP3020
# if($line -match "IP6 Realtek"){
if($line -match "Onboard NIC.IPV6."){
if($line -match "uefi\."){
$uefi2 = $line -split " " -match "uefi\."
}
if($line -match "embnic"){
$uefi2 = $line -split " " -match "embnic"
}

# Write-Host "UEFI_IPv6" $uefi2
# Write-Host .

.\cctk.cmd bootorder --bootlisttype=uefi --disabledevice=$uefi2 --valsetuppwd=
}
# For OP3010 and OP3020
# if($line -match "IP4 Realtek"){
if($line -match "Onboard NIC.IPV4."){
if($line -match "uefi\."){
$uefi = $line -split " " -match "uefi\."
}
if($line -match "embnic"){
$uefi = $line -split " " -match "embnic"
}

# Write-Host "UEFI_IPv4" $uefi
# Write-Host .

.\cctk.cmd bootorder --bootlisttype=uefi --sequence=$uefi --valsetuppwd= 
}
}

start-sleep -seconds 2

.\cctk.cmd bootorder --bootlisttype=uefi --valsetuppwd= > $UEFIfileNameAfter

# Remove-Item –path $UEFIfileName
# Remove-Item –path $UEFIfileNameAfter
```